# Activerecord using Activerecord-sqlserver-adapter returns a list of the objects but without any attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sql-server, activerecord

I have set up the the following environment:
Ubuntu 18.04 Desktop
Rails 4.1 with activerecord-sqlserver-adapter 4.1.8 and tiny_tds 2.1.2.

This is to access an existing MS SQL server 2008 database.

Once the environment set up and I was able to connect to the database using the rails console.

I created a couple of models which mapped to the existing table. One of the model is Scope.

When I rune `Scope.all` in the console, the SQL statement was generated and executed without any issue and it returns with an array of # objects but without any attributes. The number of the returned objects matched the number of records in the database. I also used other methods such as `where`, `order` etc. The SQL statements generated were executed without error. But the returned objects always contain without attributes from the database table.

I also tried the other model and the result is the same.

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: can you show the output of Scope.all?

Comment: The following is the output:    2.2.10 :002 > Scope.all
  SQL (55.7ms)  USE [TA]
  Scope Load (131.6ms)  EXEC sp_executesql N'SELECT [scopes].* FROM [scopes]'
 => #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Scope >, #<Scope >, #<Scope >, #<Scope >, #<Scope >, #<Scope >, #<Scope >, #<Scope >, #<Scope >, #<Scope >, ...]> 
2.2.10 :003 > Scope.count
   (55.5ms)  EXEC sp_executesql N'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [scopes]'
 => 26 
2.2.10 :004 >